# Jquery Dialog is not firing when call from the C# code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

This is my .aspx :

```
 <div id="divAddrCandidates" class="selector"   style="display:none">
    <div style="margin-left:10px ; margin-top:10px">
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstCandidates" runat="server" ></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
     <br />         
    <div style="margin-left:10px">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select Address" />
       <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" onclientclick="CloseAddrCandidatesWin(); return false;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This the jQuery:

```
    function OpenAddrCandidatesWin() {
        $("#divAddrCandidates").dialog({
            resizable: true,
            width: 650,
            heigh: 450,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true                
        });
        $(".selector").dialog({ dialogClass: 'no-close' });
        jQuery("#divAddrCandidates").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    }


    function CloseAddrCandidatesWin() {
        $("#<%=lstCandidates.ClientID %>").val("");
        $("#<%=lstCandidates.ClientID %>").hide();
        $("#divAddrCandidates").dialog("close");
    }
```

This is my code behind:

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
         JsonAddresses = WSJson.GetAddressCandidate(physicalAddrToProcess);
                int count = JsonAddresses.candidates.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    lstCandidates.Items.Add(JsonAddresses.candidates[i].address.ToString());
                    }


        string key = "_OpenAddrCandidatesWin";
        string script = "OpenAddrCandidatesWin();";
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(key))
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), key, script, true);
        }
}
```

What did I miss here?  The code went through without error but the dialog doesn't pop up, although I set a break at the jquery but it never stops there.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are executing the method before even dom is loaded.

Try changing `string script = "OpenAddrCandidatesWin();";` to `string script = "$(function () { OpenAddrCandidatesWin(); })";` which will wait until the dom is loaded and then execute the method.

Comment: Thanks S. but it doesn't work.  I run my code as a separate project it works well but when I hook it up to the an exist application I have this issue.

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console, I've tried to use the Debugger F12 of the IE but encounter "The script debugger failed to connect to the target process"  .  I've tried so many way but can't get rid of this message.  I set break in the jquery but look like it never stop there.

Comment: Can you try it in Chrome?

Comment: The application I'm working on is setup for IE only , can't work on other browsers.  You can see how frustrated I am :)

Comment: I can understand but I just wanted to check if there are any errors on the page load. Based on my experience Chrome is the best browser for debugging JavaScript issues.